# Google Sheets: Transform rows to columns with column breaks at 15 lines **with row data being kept together (the hard part)

Tags: google-sheets, row, multiple-columns

I have functional code that turns rows to columns and breaks the columns at 15 lines. That code is seen below.

```
=WRAPCOLS(FILTER(TOCOL('Source Sheet'!A3:E30,,0),LEN(TOCOL('Source Sheet'!A3:E30,,0))),15,)
```

The problem is that the 15-line limit breaks row data into separate columns when it gets to the 15th line. **I need row data to remain together in a column.** That means I need to force an early column break if a row's data will be broken into two columns or I need to fill the rest of a column with blank-spaced cells so that the row data that would have been divided begins in the next new column and remains together.

This issue can be seen in the example sheet below. Many of the rows of data in the Source Sheet end up divided at row 15 in the Display Sheet.   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qcRUtXKJ6y21G3leRf9EQ98xB4oyViX_Mr2sqVvGs2c/

Can you think of a way to ensure that row data is displayed completely in columns without being broken between columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Here's one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qcRUtXKJ6y21G3leRf9EQ98xB4oyViX_Mr2sqVvGs2c/edit#gid=2007990944) you may test out:*

```js
=let(Λ,index(match(,0/(A:A<>""))), Ξ,indirect("A3:D"&Λ), Σ,hstack(Ξ,wrapcols("",rows(Ξ),"")),
     Δ,query(reduce({0,1},sequence(rows(Σ)),lambda(a,c,let(σ,index(a,c,1)+counta(index(Σ,c)),vstack(a,if((σ-1)>15,{counta(index(Σ,c)),index(a,c,2)+1},{σ,index(a,c,2)}))))),"select Col2 offset 1"),
     reduce(torow(,1),sequence(max(Δ)),lambda(a,c,ifna(hstack(a,index(substitute(tocol(filter(Σ,Δ=c),1),"",)))))))
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is amazing!!! However, it creates an aberrant blank cell in the middle of the data. I wonder if you could take a look? If you can help me fix this I'll send you $20 in a method of your choice! Here's the page to real data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19AocVAjqHZZYMg7T9Y4iYyybQr6M8ltAPZ5rW8zvQ14/edit#gid=1193541375

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/OSv2wMl.png Some of the blank looking cells (in `A-4` tab) are not **TRUE** blank cells as you can see highlighted in the screenshot. this is most likely caused by the backend formulas you are using. you fix those & the issue will be fixed automatically

Comment: Combining two isblank=TRUE cells somehow results in an isblank=FALSE cell, but I solved this using some IF statements (If they're blank write the single blank cell and don't combine the blank cells). Long story short - it works!! Please let me know how I can send you $20 for a nice coffee and scone! Your code is immaculate *chef's kiss*. Email meals_juggle.06@icloud.com

Comment: (Rockin, still happy to send that gift. I fixed my email address in case that helps. Thanks again)